# A reference for an integrability property?

Tags: reference-request, inequalities, integration

In a recent paper of mine ([Compensated integrability](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.02641)), I established a functional inequality which has nice consequences. For instance, it contains the isoperimetric inequality, and it gives a new estimates for models of inviscid fluids (Euler, Boltzman, Vlasov-Poisson). When applied to discrete velocity models, with Maxwellian data, one finds the following functional inequality: if $P,Q,R,S\in L^1({\mathbb R})$ are non-negative, then 
$$\int_{{\mathbb R}^3}P(x+y+t)S(y+t-x)Q(x+t-y)R(x+y-t)\,dxdydt\le c\|P\|_2\|Q\|_1\|R\|_1\|S\|_2,$$
where $\|\cdot\|_p$ is the $1$-dimensional $L^p$-norm, and $c<\infty$ does not depend upon the data.

> Is this inequality familiar to somebody ? Does it belong to some well-known topic ?

Remark that, by symmetry and Hölder inequality, we have as well
$$\int_{{\mathbb R}^3}(P(x+y+t)S(y+t-x)Q(x+t-y)R(x+y-t))^{\frac34}dxdydt\le c\left(\|P\|_1\|Q\|_1\|R\|_1\|S\|_1\right)^{\frac34}.$$
Does the latter inequality remind you some known result ?

**Edit**. As noted by Fedja, the latter is an instance of *geometrical [Brascamp-Lieb inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brascamp%E2%80%93Lieb_inequality).*

Comment: hm, when we replace $Q$ by $\lambda Q$, LHS becomes multiplied by $\lambda$ and RHS by $\lambda^{3/4}$?

Comment: The version with correct homogeneity looks like a partial case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brascamp%E2%80%93Lieb_inequality

Comment: @fedja It would be nice to write an answer how the result follows from the inequality you cited. That would be a nice post.